# EF6/Code First and indexes: Is there anything special to do to access/use indexes?

Tags: linq, indexing, ef-code-first

I'm in my first Code First project. I just learned how to add an index on two columns.

```
    [Required]
    [Index("IX_NameAndCity", 1, IsUnique = false)]
    [MaxLength(900)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Index("IX_NameAndCity", 2, IsUnique = false)]
    [MaxLength(900)]
    public string City { get; set; }
```

Does this look right? ^^^

Is there anything special in the LINQ to utilize these indexes or is it transparent? I was half expecting to see a choice in my LINQ for '.IX_NameAndCity'.

Here's what I'm doing now:

```
 var property = _propertyRepository
            .GetProperties()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name && x.City == city);
```

Should it be something like:

```
 var property = _propertyRepository
            .GetProperties()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.IX_NameAndCity.name == name && IX_NameAndCity.City == city);
```

Or does it automagically know there's an index?
Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The index is created on the database server. Just like you don't want to explicitly refer to the index when you write a SQL query, you don't want to explicitly refer to the index when you write a LINQ query. And actually your entity won't have an `IX_NameAndCity` property. So simply use your first query:

```
var property = _propertyRepository
    .GetProperties()
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == name && x.City == city);
```

Entity Framework will construct the corresponding SQL query and pass it to the database server, and the database server will know it should (or possibly should not) use the index to speed up the query execution. It's transparent; don't worry about it.